# Symfony Doctrine ODM: backup documents

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I have to make backup logic. I have document `event` and I need to backup it. So I have to ways to do it:

**1)** Create extra field `backup` and always filter with listener on manner `->field('backup')->equals(false)`. But always filter is not a good idea I think...

**2)** Create json backup and serialize the document by jms serializer; but I've faced with having `accessor` property on `embeddedMany` translations, so I return array insted objects. This is already in production and implemented by front, so changes will be not good for all developers. Besides, such structure in another documents.
I spend a hole day to decide this problem (leave this structure and avoid errors which I get) and couldn't do it.

I even couldn't just make something like transformer (not find any solution to change data with serialize and deserialize; if you present me some example I will be very thankfull).

So this variant is not good too.

**3)** Make a collection `event_backup` with the same fields and backup them in that collection. But here I don't know how to do it? I think it's crazy to make identical document with changed collection name and just set every fields of `event` to `event_backup`. Maybe in this variant we have some more simple solution. But I didn't find.

Sure, I think you could know more right solution to do this task :). And ask you: could you advise me something?

UPDATE:

About second way: I found way to transform json. I relied on phpstorm and it didn't light methods like `setData` and `addData`. So, as often happens, stupid silly mistake.
For now I have serialization and de--. But is this way the best - the question is open...

Comment: Have you looked at the Loggable Doctrine extension? https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/loggable.md

Comment: @JasonRoman, I not really understand for what you suggest me this? Tell me a bit more, please

Comment: That extension lets you create versioning of any tables you want.  It takes away having to manually code everything you're doing, lets you rollback to previous versions, etc.  But there's lots of others ways to do this as well.